# calculate the proportion of n-node trees whose root has only one or two subtrees.

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, trees

Could we use combinatorics and generating functions to calculate the proportion of n-node trees whose root has only one or two subtrees? Here is what I tried:

The combinatorial construction for the trees with a single or two subtrees (at the root) is:

$ R = Z \cdot Z \cdot SEQ(G) + Z \cdot SEQ(G) \cdot SEQ(G) $

Thus we have:

$ R(z) = z^2 \frac{1}{1-G(z)} + z \frac{1}{[1-G(z)]^2} $

And we know that:

$ G(z) = z \cdot \frac{1+\sqrt{1-4z}}{2}$

I cannot continue since the expression became complicated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'n-node tree'? Do you mean $n$-node rooted labeled trees? $n$-node rooted unlabeled trees? $n$-node rooted unlabeled ordered trees (given your formula for $G$, maybe this is what you mean)?

Comment: @jschnei: Yes from the expressions for R and G, I assume the intention is a plane (= rooted ordered) tree, unlabelled.

Comment: Yes, ShrervatsaR is right.

Comment: @cinvro: Isn't $\mathcal{G} = \mathcal{Z} \cdot \operatorname{S\scriptsize EQ}(\mathcal{G})$, so your specification for $\mathcal{R}$ should actually be $\mathcal{R} = \mathcal{Z} \cdot \mathcal{G} + \mathcal{Z}  \cdot \mathcal{G} \cdot \mathcal{G}$ (as jschnei does in the answer below)? (Also, $G(z) = (1 - \sqrt{1-4z})/2$, and not what you've written.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible, essentially by following the technique you suggested. Let $G(z)$ be the generating function for the number of $n$-node unlabelled plane trees. It's well known (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) that this number is just the Catalan number $C_{n-1}$, so we have that

$$G(z) = z\cdot\dfrac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z} = \dfrac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2}$$

From this, we can see that the generating function for $n$-node plane trees where the root has one child is given by $H_{1}(z) = zG(z)$, and the generating function for $n$-node plane trees where the root has two ordered children is given by $H_{2}(z) = zG(z)^2$. Summing these two expressions, the generating function for the value you wish to count is given by

$$H(z) = H_1(z) + H_2(z) = z(1 - z - \sqrt{1-4z})$$

By expanding out $\sqrt{1-4z}$ according to the binomial theorem (similarly as in the derivation of Catalan numbers), we have that $\sqrt{1-4z} = 1 - 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\binom{2(n-1)}{n-1}z^{n}$. Substituting this in, we find that

$$H(z) = z^2 + 2\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\binom{2(n-2)}{n-2}\dfrac{z^{n}}{n-1}$$

It follows, that $h_{n}$, the number of plane trees with $n$ nodes and the root having one or two children equals (for $n>2$)

$$h_{n} = \dfrac{2}{n-1}\binom{2(n-2)}{n-2} = 2C_{n-2}$$

Since the total number of plane trees on $n$ nodes is $C_{n-1}$, trees with one or two children at the root form a proportion of

$$\dfrac{h_{n}}{C_{n-1}} = \dfrac{2C_{n-2}}{C_{n-1}} = \dfrac{n}{2n-3}$$

of the total number of such trees.

Comment: By the way, note that you can get the fact that (for $n > 2$ as you got) $h_n = 2g_{n-1}$ directly from the generating functions, without calculating any coefficients. Though to actually find $h_n / g_n = 2 g_{n-1} / g_n$ you need the coefficients I guess. Let's wait and see whether this is really what the OP intended, but +1 anyway for answering the question as asked.